# What happens when there is not any subscriber to a topic in MQTT?

Tags: mqtt

The situation is the following:

There is a client, a publisher, it is not subscribed to any topic. This client **has a single topic** of its own, and publishes data reguraly to it. But **there are not any other clients** that are subscribed to this topic.

So this poor and lonely client might be considered as abnormal ([Chapter 5.4.8](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718028)).

> Server implementations might monitor Client behavior to detect potential security incidents. For example:
>
> - [...]
> - Sending undeliverable messages (no subscribers to the topics)

It has [no idea about how many clients have subscribed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431489/must-a-mqtt-client-publish-to-topics-if-there-are-no-subscribers) to its topic. So it does not know that it might be considered a client with abnormal behavior.

So what happens with such a client will depend on the server implementation? What are the practices, it should be simply disconnected, but won't it try to reconnect then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you say, it depends on the server implementation, especially the QoS of the transmitted message if it is "at least once".

IMHO MQTT is a broadcasting system, not a end-to-end protocol between two machines so we don't absolutely need a subscriber every time we create a subject.

I can post anything (temperature,...) and two months later implement something that will read it, or even remove it and think of something else while my sensor still publishes data.